# Show the set is not a subspace of $L(\mathbb{R}^5,\mathbb R^4)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is my attempt to show that the set is not a subspace of $L(\mathbb{R}^5,\mathbb{R}^4)$Is the answer completely correct?Also is it correct to use different scalars as coefficients for the bases when defining transformations $T,S,\text{and} S+T$

Let $U=\{T \in L(\mathbb{R}^5,\mathbb{R}^4):\text{dimnull} T>2\}$

Is this correct?

Let $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^5$

Let $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$

Define $T \in U$ by $T(a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3+a_4v_4+a_5v_5)=a_4u_1+a_5u_2$

Define $S \in U$ by $S(b_1v_1+b_2v_2+b_3v_3+b_4v_4+b_5v_5)=b_3u_3+b_5u_4$

Then $(S+T)(c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3+c_4v_4+c_5v_5)=c_3u_3+c_4u_1+c_5(u_2+u_4)$

Since dimNull($S$+$T$)=$2$, $S+T \notin U$

Therefore U is not a subspace of $L(\mathbb{R}^5,\mathbb{R}^4)$

Answer (score 1):

You should additionally state that the nullspace of $S+T$ is given by
$$
\operatorname{Null}(S + T) = \{c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 : c_1,c_2 \in \Bbb R\}
$$
before making your conclusion about its dimension.  Other than that, your proof is correct and complete.

Comment: I could have used the same coefficients when defining each transformation right?Since the transformations are on arbitrary vectors in $R^5$?

Comment: Yes, there would have been no problem there

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct. You could explain a bit why the dimension of the nullspace of $S+T$ is $2$ though.